# Vim delete word sometimes goes into insert mode?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

Seemingly randomly, when I press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to delete a word, it will go into insert mode instead of staying in normal mode. I cannot figure out the logic behind this switch and it's getting real annoying

I first noticed this on the the VS Code Vim extension. I then went to Vim itself and found that it was also doing this anomaly. This also works with multiple keyboards and multiple computers.

Note that my installation of vanilla Vim is through Git for Windows, through cmder.

Is there a rhyme or reason to this? If so, what is it and why does it do that?

**Edit:** Turns out I was actually hitting <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> instead of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. Thanks to mMontu for helping me figure out my mental issues. lol

tl;dr: Nothings wrong, just a [`EBKAC`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/EBKAC#English) error.

Comment: The issue happening in two completely different editors that don't share a single line of code is a pretty good hint that the problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Are you positive you're actually typing `dw`, and not `cw`, or possibly `sw`? Either of those would put you in insert mode.

Comment: @romainl Or that the problem is a feature that I don't know about. That's what my latest conclusion is.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Yes, I'm positive I'm not hitting the other two combos.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, it is this is happening on completely different editors. My guess is that you (or your keyboard) are inserting some other command.

You could leave the [`recording`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording) turned on, and when you notice the issue again you can check what keys where sent to vim:

```
qa -> start recording on register a
<use vim until the issue happens>
q   -> stop recording
:register a   -> list the keys recorded
```

Another option is to save all the keys typed in a separated file (which may be better if it take a long time to reproduce the issue:

```
vim -w script file.txt ...
```

More details about this approach at [`:help -w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%2dw) and at the end of [`:help 26.4`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_26.txt.html#26%2e4).

It is worth trying to reproduce the issue without any settings or plugins,

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
```

, as explained in [`:help faq-2.5`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d2%2e5). As you are on Windows, you will need to open a cmd.exe and enter something like `<path to executable>/vim.exe -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE` (or gVim.exe).

You also mentioned are installing Vim from Git. If everything else fails, check if it also happens with the binary available [from Vim website](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll try that out real quick and see if I can get the issue to come up again.

Comment: Alright, the issue came up a bit faster this time. If I'm in the middle of a word and the <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is the first thing I do when I motion to the line, it _usually_ does it (still not 100%).

Comment: As for how it went without the settings and stuff, I think it worked? I didn't realize how many default settings were in the `.vimrc`. I'm pretty sure that it did the same thing, because when I pressed `dw` I went into what I think is insert mode (it was kinda like replace mode until I Escaped out of it. The `$` came up at the end of the word. It did have the same general behavior though as it usually didn't go into this insert mode if I had already edited something in the line before).

Comment: It is really weird that `dw` is taking into insert mode. Now, I didn't understand your last comment: did the issue happen with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE` or not? The `$` came up because you set `list` option? And as a last resort, try downloading the official version of Vim.

Comment: So, some psychology time: turns out I was actually just hitting `cw` instead of `dw` and apparently when I was hastily reading the script files earlier today, confirmation bias tricked my brain into seeing a `dw` when it was actually a `cw`. Regardless, problem solved, it was just a `ID10T` error. lol